# Excel Pivot Chart - Percentage of Rows Containing Yes

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

Okay so I have a simple named range we'll call "RangeX", the results of a survey we ran. I have 800 rows of data

In response to one of the questions we had 4 possible answers (multiple choices allowed).
**I'll just make up some answers**
1) Fool
2) Jerk
3) Normal
4) Nice

Now in my raw data I have 4 columns and values in each row are either Yes or No (I can make it 1 or 0 if it simplifies things but Yes/No are preferable)

What I'm trying to do is create a pivot chart a simple bar graph based on percentage of row count in the Named Range containing yes in that particular column.

**For example**
The 4 columns:
**Fool | Jerk | Normal | Nice**
Yes  |  No  |  Yes   | Yes

Lets say out of the 800 rows 200 people checked "Fool" then I would have 200 "Yes" values, so the bar should be 25%

400 people checked "Jerk" then I would have 400 "Yes" values, so the bar should be 50%.

Essentially each bar is based on row count since each row could have a Yes in multiple columns.

Sorry I hope I didn't make this question longer than it had to be...

Thanks,

Kenny

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table is overkill for this situation. Use the `COUNTIF` and `COUNTA` functions for each column of the answers to the survey. Assuming the first answer is in column A, this formula displays the percentage of "Yes" answers.

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A801,"=Yes")/COUNTA(A2:A801)
```

Repeat the formula for each of the three other columns, and make a bar chart from the percentages. This question about how to [Calculate percentage of answers in Excel](https://superuser.com/a/1116498/615410) has some additional details.