# Calculate percentage of answers in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet that looks like this:

[image]

I want a function that will tell me the percentage of each response. So 36% blue, 27% red, etc. I found [this article](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/qt/excel-count.htm) that shows how to do this kind of thing, but only with a yes/no answer. I want to be able to calculate it, so that if I add another row, and the next person's favourite colour is purple, it will include that in the response.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$12,E2)/COUNTA($B$2:$B$12)`
Countif to count colours
CountA to count answers
Countif / CountA to have the percentage of each colour
$B$2:$B$12 the range of colours
E2 the unique value of each colour

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now, is it possible to automatically generate the list of colours?

Comment: You can copy all the colours paste it in new column and use remove duplicates (Data Tab)

Answer (score 1):

In Column C list the unique values (can also get them from Advanced Filtering). Then in D1 `=COUNTIF($B:$B,"="&C1)/(COUNTA($B:$B)-1)` and fill that down.

Comment: forgot the divide by total at first

Comment: `COUNTA($B:$B)` will include the title row in the count.  You will want to subtract 1 from the denominator to make up for it. `(COUNTA($B:$B) - 1)`

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner didn't catch there was a title row. Fixed my post.